# Is try-catch meant to prevent or handle errors? (in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, web, try-catch, local-storage, web-storage

Recently I had a discussion with my coworker, about using `try` and `catch` to notify errors or avoid them.

This is my coworker's approach:

```
import Config from 'config';

export const getUserFromLocalStorage = () => {
  const key = Object.keys(localStorage).find(value => value === `${Config.applicationId}/currentUser`);

  try {
    return key ? JSON.parse(localStorage[key]) : {};
  } catch (e) {
    return {};
  }
};
```

> Which means, he doesn't care about the given error and he is just carrying of returning an object in order to continue the process

and mine is:

```
import Config from 'config';

export const getUserFromLocalStorage = () => {
  const key = Object.keys(localStorage).find(value => value === `${Config.applicationId}/currentUser`);

  try {
    return key ? JSON.parse(localStorage[key]) : {};
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('the given error', e); // Just simple notifier for this example
  }
};
```

but my approach, still has a problem which is that it will return `undefined` (which can crash internally my app), that can easily fix it using `finally` and returning a default value but it doesn't sound a good practice to me.

## THE QUESTION

So what will the balance using `try` `catch` and `finally` if needed, to make my application stable.
Is there something wrong with our approach?
In particular, we can't trust the data that is coming from the `localStorage`, so what will be the best approach for this implementation?

Comment: `is that it will return undefined (which can crash internaly my app)` : you should document that the method might return `undefined` and your code calling it should be able to handle that. Equally your coworker's empty object might cause an exception for calling code. The main thing is to document what is returned in an error state and let your callers decide what to do.

Comment: No, you would not use `finally` to return a default for the error case.

Comment: @Bergi what would be the utility of `finally`

Comment: @JoseAPL For things that should be executed regardless of what happens in `try` or `catch`. You usually don't want to always `return` from there. The prominent use case is closing resources.

Comment: @Bergi true, I just forgot what was `finally` for :)

Answer (score 3):

Since `finally` is executed in either case, whether something was thrown or not, it is not the place to return a default value. It is also questionable whether you need to log the error in great detail or not. It all depends on whether something is an *expected error* or a truly *exceptional circumstance* and who can do something about it.

Is it rather likely or possible that the value stored is invalid JSON? And you have a "backup plan" for what to do in that case? And there's nothing the user and/or developer can do about it? Then don't bother anyone with it. Maybe you want to `console.log` a message that might aid in debugging, but other than that just carry on with the program flow. There's most certainly no need to bug the user with an `alert` if a) the user didn't initiate the action and b) there's nothing for them to do about it either.

Considerations to take:

1. Whether to `catch` an error in the first place:

   - is it an expected error which may naturally occur during the program flow?
   - is it an error you can do something about?
   - do you have any plan what to do if you caught the error?
2. Whether to log an error:

   - does this log do anyone any good?
   - will anybody ever see that log entry?
   - does it give anyone any useful information that can lead to fixing the issue?
3. Whether to bug the user about something:

   - did the user initiate the action?
   - does the user expect some form of response, positive or negative?
   - can the user do anything to fix the problem?

Whether to return an empty object or nothing/`null`/`undefined` depends on what the function's responsibility is. Is the function defined to always return an object? Then it should `return {}` from `catch`. Or is "nothing" a valid response when the expected object doesn't exist? Then perhaps `return false`.

Overall, your coworker's approach seem very reasonable to me.

Comment: Ok, if for any reason there is an invalid JSON object in the `localStorage` and  I will return an empty object, assuming that the `getUserFromLocalStorage` will always work and return something (valid), which is something "incorrect"? since there was an error, I understand your explanation tho. Actually, we shouldn't even return an empty object if the key doesn't exist.       

I guess it all depends on what's the contract for the `getUserFromLocalStorage` function. what do you think? :)

Comment: Errors aren't always fatal, meaning in the normal flow of a program there may be expected errors which can simply be handled silently (swept under the rug). Error !== always ring alarm bells. Beyond that, yes, *you* decide how you want your function to behave on the outside.

Comment: thanks, you deserve the bounty for a great explanation and use cases :)

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, where you are working with `localStorage` (which almost always inevitably means working with JSON.parse()), it's always best practice to wrap your processing in try-catch. This is because both localStorage and JSON.parse have exceptions as a normal part of their error handling and it is usually possible to fallback to a default or initial value gracefully.

A pattern I use is something like as follows:

```
const DEFAULT_VALUE = {};
try {
  const result = JSON.parse(result);
  return result || DEFAULT_VALUE;
} catch (e) {
  console.warn('Error parsing result', e);
} 

return DEFAULT_VALUE;
```

This way, you have consistent error handling and default value fallback.

In general, you shouldn't need use try-catch unless you can and will safely handle the error and generate a useful fallback. Most try-catch blocks tend to sit at the bottom of a call-stack for this reason, so that they catch unplanned errors, handle them gracefully for the user, but log them noisily with a call-stack to the console for the developer to investigate/handle correctly/workaround.

Answer (score -1):

I think the most important thing is that user satisfaction. At the end of the day, the program is used by the normal user. The user needs to continue his work using the program without any interruptions.

So i think that the best practices is to use `try` to run code and `catch` if there any errors and notify developer and/or user that there is an exception, and use `finally` to overcome the exception by returning a valid object.

In this way user is also able to continue the work and the developer also can check the error in log file for future debugging.
This is my personal idea.